# Problem with passing argument in onclick event while using innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'd like to simply fetch and display data from api, to each item I want to add button where its possible to click and add item to favorite. If im trying to pass item.name as an argument to the function I got an error

> index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buzz is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1:10)

what is strange for me if I pass item.id it works fine.

```
async function getAllBeers() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers");
  const data = await response.json();
  displayAllBeers(data);
}
getAllBeers();

function displayAllBeers(data) {
  const beersContainer = document.getElementById("beersContainer");
  data.map((beer) => {
    console.log(beer.name);
    beersContainer.innerHTML += `
      <div class='beerContainer'>
          <h3 class='name'>${beer.name}</h3>
          <img src='${beer.image_url}'></img>
          <p>${beer.description}</p>
          <button onclick='addToFav(${beer.name})'>Add to Favourite</button>
      </div>
      `;
  });
}

function addToFav(name) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what this becomes when the placeholder is replaced with data:

```
<button onclick='addToFav(${beer.name})'>Add to Favourite</button>
```

It becomes this:

```
<button onclick='addToFav(Buzz)'>Add to Favourite</button>
```

So you're trying eo execute this:

```
addToFav(Buzz)
```

Just as the error states, `Buzz` is not defined.  Presumably you intend for this literal value to be a *string*:

```
addToFav('Buzz')
```

Strings have quotes around them.  So your dynamic code generation logic needs to include those quotes:

```
<button onclick="addToFav('${beer.name}')">Add to Favourite</button>
```

(Note that I also replaced the quotes around the attribute value with double-quotes, which is more HTML-standard and prevents these single-quotes from interfering with the attribute value.)

Answer (score 1):

You were missing to quote the `'${beer.name}'`

I suggest you delegate

```js
const beersContainer = document.getElementById("beersContainer");
const displayAllBeers = data => {
  beersContainer.innerHTML = data.map((beer) => `
    <div class='beerContainer'>
      <h3 class="name">${beer.name}</h3>
      <img src="${beer.image_url}" />
      <p>${beer.description}</p>
      <button class="add">Add to Favourite</button>
    </div>`).join("");
};

const addToFav = name => {
  console.log(name);
};

beersContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".add")
  if (tgt) addToFav(tgt.closest(".beerContainer").querySelector(".name").textContent)
});

async function getAllBeers() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers");
  const data = await response.json();
  displayAllBeers(data);
}
getAllBeers();
```

```html
<div id="beersContainer"></div>
```